# Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]' in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

** I am getting this error**

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic from Function 'get':.
Tried calling: []("url")
Found: [](dynamic) => dynamic
```

**my code where I am receiving the data from firestore is this..**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:riyazat_quiz/services/database.dart';
import 'package:riyazat_quiz/views/create_quiz.dart';
import 'package:riyazat_quiz/widgets/widgets.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Stream quizStream;
  DatabaseService databaseService = DatabaseService(); // this is to call the getQuizData()  async{
return await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Quiz").snapshots();
  }


 Widget quizList(){
   return Container(
     child: StreamBuilder(
       stream:quizStream ,
       builder: (context,snapshort){
         return snapshort.data == null ? CircularProgressIndicator(): ListView.builder(
             scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
             shrinkWrap: true,
             itemCount : snapshort.data.documents.length ,
             itemBuilder : (context,index){ return QuizTile(url:snapshort.data.documents[index].get['url'],
               title:snapshort.data.documents[index].get['title'] ,
               desc: snapshort.data.documents[index].get['desc'],);}

         );
       }
     ),
   );
 }

 @override
  void initState() {
  databaseService.getQuizData().then((val){
    setState(() {
      quizStream =val;

    });
  });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: appBar(context),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      body:
        Column(
          children: [
            quizList(),
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateQuiz()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),

    );
  }
}

class QuizTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String  url,title,desc;
  QuizTile({@required this.url,@required this.title,@required this.desc});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.network(url),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(title),
                Text(desc),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***can someone tell me where I am going wrong***

> ps: this is a quiz app where I am getting the data from the firestore,
> using streams.
> data saved on the firestore has three fields, "url", "title" "desc".
> I want to retrieve them in the below widget and want to display them in a stack, but this error got me stuck in-between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
itemCount : snapshort.data.docs.length ,
itemBuilder : (context,index){ 
  return QuizTile(url:snapshort.data.docs[index].data()['url'],
      title:snapshort.data.docs[index].data()['title'] ,
      desc: snapshort.data.docs[index].data()['desc'],
   );
  }
);
```

Since you are reference a collection, then you need to use `docs` which will retrieve a list of documents inside that collection:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query_snapshot.dart#L18

Then to access each field in the document, you need to call `data()`

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Peter Haddad is correct. Just to highlight the difference with an example from my own code:

The previous version of code which created the same error:

```
snapshot.data.docs[index].data["chatRoomID"]
```

Updated version of code which solved the error:

```
snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["chatRoomID"]
```

Comment: You should describe the error that was made in addition to just providing the correction so that the person knows why the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Version:

```
snapshot.data[i]['Email'],
```

```
Future getRequests() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Buyer Requests").get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
```

```
body: FutureBuilder(
          initialData: [],
          future: getRequests(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            indexLength = snapshot.data.length;
            if (snapshot.hasData)
              return SizedBox(
                child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: indexLength,
                  controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0),
                  onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                    'assets/images/shafiqueimg.jpeg'),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                snapshot.data[i]['Email'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                snapshot.data[i]['Time'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                                    ),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data[i]['Description'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 8,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(5)),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.grey[300])),
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.category_outlined),
                                      title: Text(
                                        'Category : ${snapshot.data[i]['Category']}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                   SizedBox(height: 8),
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(5)),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.grey[300])),
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.location_pin),
                                      title: Text(
                                        snapshot.data[i]['Location'],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(5)),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.grey[300])),
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(
                                        Icons.attach_money,
                                        color: kGreenColor,
                                      ),
                                      title: Text(
                                        'Rs.${snapshot.data[i]['Budget']}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: kGreenColor,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(5)),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.grey[300])),
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.timer),
                                      title: Text(
                                        'Duration : ${snapshot.data[i]['Duration']}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 35,
                                  ),
                                  RaisedButton(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                    child: Text('Send Offer'),
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // Respond to button press
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15,
                                  ),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "${i + 1}/$indexLength",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            else
              return Center(
                child: Text("Null"),
              );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are referencing a collection, you must use docs to acquire a list of the documents included in that collection:

[https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud firestore/cloud firestore/lib/src/query snapshot.dart#L18](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud%20firestore/cloud%20firestore/lib/src/query%20snapshot.dart#L18)

then you must call data() in order to access each field in the document.